# What's an antonym for "tyranny"?

Tags: antonyms

Is there a perfect antonym for the word "Tyranny", meaning the two words could be used in the same place in a sentence and always function correctly, but have opposite meanings...

i.e.
The King ruled with tyranny.
The King ruled with...

Comment: I think the correct word is Justice.

Comment: Justice sounds right in this context, but then the best choice for antonym of Justice isn't Tyranny. it would be Injustice of Unfairness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends what you are looking for. If you were meaning the type of rule the king had, the antonym would be something having to do with democracy, like:

> **egalitarianism**

However, if you are asking about the harshness of the king's rule, then you would probably use:

> **clemency**

Comment: Ah thank you, egalitarianism is what I was looking for. I needed a word which could be juxtaposed with Tyranny to make a title for a paper. "Tyranny and Egalitarianism" works nicely.

Comment: Idiot: I'd say an *egalitarian king* is by definition an oxymoron.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, @Third Idiot, although _egalitarian king_ is an oxymoron, I could imagine a tyrannically egalitarian government. I can even think of at least one historical example.

Comment: Egalitarian is the belief in equality of all people. No king would be egalitarian. He would be like common?

Answer (score 9):

[**benevolence**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benevolent) (from thefreedictionary)

benevolent - *intending or showing kindness; "a benevolent society"*

Comment: Since *benevolent dictatorship* is a well-establish phrase, I would say *benevolence* is the right adjective here.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That was my thinking, and I probably should have said so in the answer. Thanks for filling the gap.

Answer (score 2):

Benevolence is nice (in more ways than one!) but I'm not sure it's exactly the *opposite* of [tyranny](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tyranny), which has to do with (a) the scope of the tyrant's power (i.e. absolute) and (b) the tyrant's use and abuse of that power. So while a tyrant is unlikely to be benevolent, I don't feel that benevolence and tyranny are quite opposites.

What about [**latitude**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/latitude), in the sense of freedom from narrow restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

I would say the opposite of *tyrrany* is *anarchy* -- no government at all.

Comment: But you can't actually *rule* "with anarchy".

Comment: Indeed. Anarchy is a *complete and utter failure to rule*.

Comment: I always think of it from the other side. Anarchy is the *complete and utter refusal to* **be** *ruled*.

Answer (score 1):

[Benevolence?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benevolence)

Less commonly, [grace?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grace) (as in "Would it please Your Grace...?")

Once upon a time, it was considered a good thing if royalty displayed [condescension](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/condescension), but that word has almost exclusively negative connotations now.

Answer (score 1):

try [laissez faire](http://www.wordnik.com/words/laissez%20faire)

> ```
>   –noun
> ```
>
> 1. An economic doctrine that opposes governmental regulation of or
>   interference in commerce beyond the
>   minimum necessary for a
>   free-enterprise system to operate
>   according to its own economic laws.
>
> 1. Noninterference in the affairs of others.

Comment: @pageman: You can have a *laissez faire* attitude or policy - but you can't *rule* with it, or with any derivative word-forms I know of.

Comment: @Fumble check the example in Wodnik: 3.(economics, politics) Practicing or representing governmental noninterference, or minimal interference, especially in economic affairs; pertaining to free-market capitalism. I think the city should take a laissez faire approach to this; getting involved would only make things worse. Libertarian/Soft Paternalism might be related to this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_paternalism)

Comment: @pageman: Like I said, a government can adopt a laissez faire policy in some particular area. I just don't see you can characterise the entire 'rule' as laissez faire in OP's context.

Comment: @Fumble actually, in theory, you can :)

Comment: @pageman: On reflection, yes of course you can. My criticism was at the very least excessive. In some ways *laissez-faire* doesn't sit well with *rule*, but they aren't at all mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Fumble you mind voting for my answer? haha ;)

Comment: @pageman: Now you've made me think about it, I *will* upvote yours. Usually I only vote for the one best answer, but in this case obviously I rate my own *benevolence* top. I really can't buy into *latitude*, so you can take the silver medal!

Comment: @Fumble +1 your answer :) quid pro quo :)

Answer (score 0):

*Democracy*. Check [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/tyranny).